# Can I use a wildcard when setting up area registration in an MVC route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an address like the following:

```
www.stack.com/content-00000/solutions-about
```

My route registration (unverified but maybe 90% okay) looks like this:

```
public class ContentAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Content";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Content_default",
                "content-{id}/{title}",
                new { controller = "Server", action = "Get" },
                new { id = @"^\d{5}$" }
                new { title = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Can someone confirm if this is the correct way for me to do the route

```
a) Go to the "Content" Area
b) Go to the "Server" Controller
b) Go to the "Get " action 
c) Five digits that follow will be put into a parameter called id?
```

Also how can I make this go to another action such as "error" if the "Content-" is not followed by five numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You point from a) to d) looks correct.
To implement last part, I would add one more rule immediately **after** the rule you shown, which would state exactly the same, but without regular expression, and maybe with marking 'id' as optional, something like:
`

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Content_Error",//or maybe *null* here
                "content-{id}/{title}",
                new { controller = "Server", action = "Get" },
                new { id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                   title = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

`

As this rule is following your main rule, it will be executed only if ID does not satisfy your regex in first rule.